# Cloud run invoking another Cloud run with "Allow internal traffic and traffic from Cloud Load Balancing" fails with error 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have built a Django backend and deployed it in cloud run. I have also built a react frontend that was also deployed in cloud run. Frontend calls Django backend. Everything works while backend Allow all traffic, when I change it to "Allow internal traffic and traffic from Cloud Load Balancing"  I get 403 error. Both are using VPC connector. And also both are on un-authenticated cloud Run.

Comment: Error `403 Forbidden` is a permission problem. Traffic of some type is happening. Your question lacks details on what you have deployed and how everything is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Focus on your architecture and where the code is running.

- Your backend run on Cloud Run
- Your front ent? it's served by Cloud Run, but executed on your browser.

That's why, your browser haven't a serverlessVPC connector or something like that and the request to the backend come from the internet, nothing from your Cloud Run frontend.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, what would be the solution given this architecture given both backend and frontend serving in Cloud Run?

Comment: Basically if I understood it correctly there is no way to limit the traffic to internal give current architecture and the only way is to make the backend authenticated. I have a problem with that because I have user authentication in Django and I think I have a problem when I use the google token instead of my Django application tokens.

Comment: You are correct, you must set your backend public. But don't activate the Google Cloud authentication if you manage the authentication on your side. It's not a design that I recommend but many do that today.